# child's padding is bigger than parent's size

Tags: html, css, padding

I would like to make my  tag is big as the parent div (#logo, and i'm having trouble making a 100% padding without making it bigger than the parent's tag.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#logo {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sHTtXk4.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#logo a {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwbo9exg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding` and add `display` for `a` tag

```
div#logo a {
    background: #fff; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* padding: 100%; */
    display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
}
```